# Exception "ConnectionResetError" after awaiting subprocesss.stdout.drain() from asyncio.subprocess module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have faced with exception when tried to run outer python file with asyncio.subprocess. Here is my code:

```
import asyncio
async def external():
    writing_process=await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell("pwd",
                                                            stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
                                                            stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
                                                            stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
                                                            cwd="/home/user1/folder1")
    print(await writing_process.stdout.read())
    writing_process.stdin.writelines([b"python test.py"])
    await writing_process.stdin.drain()
    print(await writing_process.stdout.read())
asyncio.run(run_outer_py_file())
```

Here is the output:

```
b'/home/bykov/nra_banks\n'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionResetError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-67bbc190049c> in async-def-wrapper()

<ipython-input-9-67bbc190049c> in external()
     11     print(await writing_process.stdout.read())
     12 await external()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py in drain(self)
    346             # would not see an error when the socket is closed.
    347             await sleep(0, loop=self._loop)
--> 348         await self._protocol._drain_helper()
    349 
    350 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/asyncio/streams.py in _drain_helper(self)
    200     async def _drain_helper(self):
    201         if self._connection_lost:
--> 202             raise ConnectionResetError('Connection lost')
    203         if not self._paused:
    204             return

ConnectionResetError: Connection lost
```

May anybody explain me, where am I wrong?

Comment: Please try to create a minimal runnable example that others can run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have just edited my comment according to @user4815162342

Comment: Here the problem is that `pwd` exits quickly, which writing to it fail with an exception, the exception being reported by `drain()`. You need to either ensure that the subprocess is alive or catch `IOError`. Perhaps the same problem applies to your original code, where the subprocess exits due to some error.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks. As I understand I can put all the comands in bash file as first rough solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to @user4815162342 I understand that I should put all my comands in bash script and use name of python file as comand line parameter.

So my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user1/anaconda3/bin/activate my_env
python "$@"
```

And my python code:

```
import asyncio
async def run_external(script, *args):
    writing_process=await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell("bash test.sh "+' '.join((script,)+args), 
                                                      stdin=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
                                                      stdout=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE, 
                                                      stderr=asyncio.subprocess.PIPE,
                                                      cwd="/home/user1/folder1")
    print((await writing_process.stdout.read()).decode())
asyncio.run(run_external("test.py"))
```

Comment: Note that `create_subprocess_shell("bash test.sh "+' '.join((script,)+args), stdin=...)` leaves you vulnerable to quoting issues; for example, your code won't correctly pass arguments that contain spaces to the subprocess. You can instead use `create_subprocess_exec("bash", "test.sh", script, *args, stdin=...)`